# Правильная установка gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

В начале процесса установки **GULP** по 'getting started' from GULP GITHUB, я столкнулся с непонятным для меня этапом:

> 1. Install gulp globally:
>
> If you have previously installed a version of gulp globally, please
>   run npm rm --global gulp to make sure your old version doesn't collide
>   with gulp-cli.

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

**ВОПРОС:** Для чего нужно устанавливать **gulp-cli**, и что делает эта команда `npm rm --global gulp`, удаляет что то старое, кэш или еще что-то?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Комманда `npm rm --global gulp` удаляет глобально установленный пакет gulp, если таковой есть в системе.

Команда `npm install --global gulp-cli` устанавливает пакет gulp-cli в глобальное хранилище, иначе говоря в специальное место, которое обычно внесено в $PATH, дабы после установки в консоли можно было запустить команду `gulp` в любой директории.

Но для полноценной работы галпа нужно установить в папку с проектом галп модуль:
`npm install --save-dev gulp`

Если не установить gulp в папку проекта, то при попытке запуска команды gulp вы увидите соответствующее сообщение об ошибке.

Более подробное объяснение: http://blog.dwaynecrooks.com/post/110903139442/why-do-we-need-to-install-gulp-globally-and

Comment: Microfed@ Так а что именно это за пакет - gulp-cli ? Для его его нужно устанавливать?